# Predefined view vs query at runtime - mysql

Tags: mysql, database-performance

i need to know which one will be more efficient way of doing.

### method 1: create predefined view in mysql as follows.

> create view TestView As
>   select * from Table1
>   union all
>   select * from Table2

after creating this view, im quering as

> select * from TestView where col_value = 5

### method 2: im running following query at runtime

> select * from Table1 where col_value = 5
>   union all
>   select * from Table2 where col_value = 5

in first method the view can have more than 100,000 records. from which it has to find records "col_value = 5".

Both will give me same result but i wanted to know which one is more good in performance wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your "Method 1", your query

```
SELECT * FROM TestView WHERE col_value = 5
```

is actually equivalent to:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM Table2
) AS v
WHERE col_value = 5
```

This basically means: "select everything from each table, merge the results and then filter out". All records from both tables will be scanned and copied to a temporary table, possibly on disk. Besides, this query is unable to use an index on `col_value` if such an index exists.

Method 2 is preferable.

Note this is not always true. In some (many) cases, MySQL is able to do a smart merge of the view definition with the query using the view (this is called the [`MERGE` algorithm](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/view-algorithms.html)). In such cases, the performance would be almost exactly the same. In your example, the presence of an `UNION`clause prevents this optimisation.

P.S: check out [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/execution-plan-information.html)

Comment: thanks for the reply..As for another scenario I have to use a view joining (not UNION) 2 tables… then method 1 or method 2 will preferable?

Comment: It really depends on the view definition. In most cases, when the view  does not contain any of the constructs listed in the page I linked, either approach will perform the same.